# Laravel select missing columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, inner-join, laravel-5.5

## Objective

I'm trying to select some columns from a multiple inner join query.

I have a model called `Item` and this model belongs to the other three `Produto`, `Unidade`and `Marca`

## Problem

I'm not getting the full result declared on my query. Only some columns are being shown.

## What I tried

I have already tried to put everything in one `->select()` , but I had the same issue. I've checked the relations configuration is working in other part of the code

## Result Obtained

Only the columns from first and the last `addSelect()` are being shown.

`var_dump()` [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acrUH.png)

## Code

```
public function download()
{
      $item = new Item;
// $data = $item->query()
 $data =  DB::table('items')
 ->join('produtos', 'items.produto_id', '=', 'produtos.id')
 ->join('unidades', 'items.unidade_id', '=', 'unidades.id')
    ->join('marcas', 'items.marca_id', '=', 'marcas.id')        
     ->select('items.codigo','items.nome')
      ->addSelect('items.metrica_cod', 'items.metrica')
        ->addSelect('produtos.codigo', 'produtos.nome')
      ->addSelect('unidades.codigo', 'unidades.nome')
        ->addSelect('marcas.codigo', 'marcas.nome')
      
     
  ->get();
      var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: So the `select` columns `codigo` and `nome` are being ignored completely?

Comment: Exactly ! I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Can you please add some database structure ?

Comment: I found the problem. When we have columns with same name we need to define alias other wise only of them will appear. Thanks everybody for caring about @TimBiegeleisen